# Is there any way i can run cypher command starting from :Param using py2neo 2021.0.0

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, py2neo

Well, in neo4j i am trying to achieve this simple query to save the sparql keyword to use in later query and graph.run is not allowing me to do it. It is showing a syntax error

```
graph.run(":PARAM sparql: 'PREFIX sch: <http://schema.org/> CONSTRUCT{?item a sch:item; sch:legalIdentity ?legalIdentity} WHERE { {?item p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q783794 optional { ?item wdt:P1278 ?legalIdentity} } UNION {?item p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q4830453 optional { ?item wdt:P1278 ?legalIdentity}} UNION {?item p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q43229 optional { ?item wdt:P1278 ?legalIdentity}} UNION {?item p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6881511 optional { ?item wdt:P1278 ?legalIdentity}}}'")
```

And following line is the cypher query which uses sparql keyword

```
graph.run('CALL n10s.rdf.import.fetch("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=" + apoc.text.urlencode($sparql), "RDF/XML", { headerParams: { Accept: "application/rdf+xml"} });')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:PARAM` command is a client-side browser/shell built-in. It does not exist in Cypher itself. As mentioned by [@fbiville](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277128/fbiville), you will need to pass a dict of parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary of parameters to the `run` method, as documented [here](https://py2neo.org/2021.0/database/index.html#py2neo.database.Graph.run).